# 503 Backend fetch failed after install an extension

Tags: magento2, error, extensions

I downloaded an extension from the magento markert and when I installed this extension the magento stopped working.I dont see any maintenance.flag so this is not the problem, some idea please?

I have tried everything that has occurred to me..

Thanks you so much!
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this issue most likely related to stupid bitnami stack, https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/troubleshoot-magento-issues/ ,

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me also, but not in this situation. A few things that come to my mind:

- does the extension files moved successfully? check that path
- does the file name from the second image have appropriate permissions?
- does the database connection work?

More exactly, this error is due to the Varnish configuration. Take a read here, I did something similar in my case:
[Magento 2 503 Backend Fetch Failed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125951/magento-2-503-backend-fetch-failed)

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: I did a new Virtual Machine because i couldn't do nothing but i saw the web page was atacking to localhost:81, this port isn't apache, it's varnish service. This can be a reason. Maybe when i installed the extension the BD was corrupted.. I dont know